# Is there a good source of information for political intrigues?

Tags: resources, research

Every time I watch a TV show from India or China, I am amazed about all the different subtle political intrigues that go on, so I would like to know if there's some kind of books that covers a lot of them, so I can use it as a source of inspiration in one of the books I would like to write sometime this year. Is there a good source for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truth is stranger than fiction.

Look to history for inspiration.  Read books about famous spies, scandals, wartime espionage, or the histories of kings and queens throughout history.